# Правильность составления предложения

Tags: употребление-слов

Правильно ли составлено предложение: "В наличии отсроченные и просроченные платежи отсутствуют"? Можно ли употреблять эту фразу в таком виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Отсутствуют в наличии" - это какая-то дребедень, точнее плеоназм.

Comment: плеоназм - это дублирование смысла. Здесь этого нет. Слышали выражение: "нет в наличии". Так вот это тоже самое, только заменено синонимом. Или я не права?

Comment: Вы слышали фразу "при наличии отсутствия"? Это пародия на махровый канцелярит, у Ильфа и Петрова встречается. Так у вас то же самое. ))

Comment: Даже не канцелярит, а алогизм. Получается, что в наличии есть какое-то отсутствие.

Comment: Наверное, можно просто сказать: Отсроченные и просроченные платежи в настоящее время отсутствуют.